# Does dominated Covergence Theorem hold for Riemann integral?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

Does dominated Covergence Theorem hold for Riemann integral?

***Statement of the DCT:***

Theorem - Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $L^1$ such that (a) $f_n\rightarrow f$, and (b) there exists a nonnegative $g\in L^1$ such that $|f_n|\leq g$ a.e. for all $n$. Then $f\in L^1$ and $\int f = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_n$.

Comment: Consider $(a_n)$ an enumeration of the rationals over $[0,1]$ and $f_n(x) = \sum \mathbf 1_{\{x = a_n\}}$.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1231378/491675) for when it holds.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. It is possible that $f$ is not Riemann-integrable but is Lebesgue integrable, so you should interpret $\int f$ as a Lebesgue-integral for this to hold.